# Password protected web page in restful webservices using apache shiro

Tags: shiro

I want to make my website pages password protected.I make the website using restful webservices in java using jersey.So can any one tell me how to protect my web pages using apache shiro.Any one have implemented example to securing a website using apache shiro if yes than plz share the example.I shall be thankful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For protecting your webservices using shiro you can use following template files and can customize with your own requirements. Include the jars or add to pom as required.

Add these to **web.xml**

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>Shiro</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.IniShiroFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Shiro</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Now for **shiro.ini** to be place in **WEB-INF** (I am using basic Authentication with username and roles in shiro.ini which you can use from database etc as per your need, Assuming that /rest is the url for jersey rest services)

```
[main]



    [urls]
    /rest/** = noSessionCreation,authcBasic
    /**= anon

    [users]
    admin=admin
```

Comment: thanks do u have any example implemented to securing a website using apache shiro if yes than plz share the example i shall be thankful :)

Comment: I have added few resources to this git repo once you get i will delete the repo. You can use this to understand. https://github.com/devmgs/shirotest

Comment: so may i delete the repo as not want the code floating public